# Melhor/Segura forma para transferir dados sensiveis para uma aplicação android através de JSON

Tags: android, mysql, json, login

Estou a tentar desenvolver uma aplicação para android que irá trabalhar com uma base de dados neste caso MySQL e estava a pensar fazer a comunicação entre a base de dados e a aplicação através de JSON os dados teriam que ser transferidos sobre SSL mas mesmo assim talvez não fosse a melhor opção para transferir dados de utilizadores entre outros..

Será que me podiam dar umas luzes de como o fazer de uma forma que seja minimamente segura?

Comment: bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Poderia complementar sua pergunta. Linguagem, tecnologia, até onde você já chegou, etc. Dê uma olhada em [ask]

Answer (score 5):

Encripte seu conteúdo após a serialização, e antes de enviá-lo; Desencripte quando receber no servidor, e antes de passar o *payload* para seu interpretador JSON.

Utilize um algoritmo criptográfico reversível e resistente, como [Rijndael](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.6/org/bouncycastle/crypto/engines/RijndaelEngine.html). Para segurança adicional utilize chaves baseadas em uma fórmula que varie com o tempo.

Answer (score 0):

A opção mais segura que vejo seria SSL, mesmo. Porém, se você deseja utilizar algo menos robusto, serialize a string JSON e faz o envio via POST.

É uma opção :D

Comment: Acredito que SSL só iria proteger o pacote de ser capturado na rede, mas ainda estaria visível para o dono do celular.